# How to prevent people not in my contact list from chatting with me

Tags: blocking, windows-live-messenger

I am using Windows 7 and someone who is not in my Windows Messenger contact list has been harassing me with sexual requests. This is most irritating and I had searched everywhere for ways to totally block this person from contacting me but to no avail. Each time my Messenger goes online, this person will message me, be it day or night.

How can I either block this person permanently, or prevent anybody who is not on my contacts list from chatting with me?

Answer (score 1):

Open the options window by clicking your name near the top right of messenger and select "More options" (at the bottom).  Of the tabs on the left, select Privacy.  Then click on the "Edit settings" button.  That should take you via browser to your Live privacy settings.  Does this page have what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you but how do I select some Messenger friends or All Messenger friends. If I drag the marker to No one, I don't get the irritating message but this would not allow my actual messenger friends to reach me. Your advice, please.